# match article title with tags listed in another table

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

I need a query in mysql that can list out matched tag_names in one table with article_title column in another table

```
tags table
------------
tag_id  tag_name
--------------
1      travel
2      tickets
3      business
4      america
```

```
article table
-------------
article_id  article_title
---------   --------------
1           travel tips to america
2           cheap tickets for favorite destinations
3           prices for business class tickets to america
```

```
expected output
--------------
article_id tag_id    tag_name
---------- -------   ----------
1           1        travel
1           4        america
2           2        tickets
3           3        business
3           2        tickets
3           4        america
```

Comment: Hint: Use a join ... have you tried a query yet?

Comment: i tried with match-against, but ...

Comment: Did you setup a full text index on the table(s)?

Comment: yes i setup full text index on tag_name and article_title

Comment: In my opinion, you should have a third table, with a many-to-many relationship.  In other words, a table with just `id`, `tag_id`, `article_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be as follows:

```
SELECT a.article_id, t.tag_id, t.tag_name 
FROM article a
JOIN tags t
ON a.article_title LIKE CONCAT('%', t.tag_name, '%')
ORDER BY a.article_id;
```

However, if you want to tokenize the tags with **space**, you should replace line 4 of the query with

`ON a.article_title LIKE CONCAT('% ', t.tag_name, ' %')`

This will not consider the tag **america** in the titles like

**The american dream is a national ethos of the United States**

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables as follows:

```
SELECT article_id, tag_id, tag_name
FROM tags as t 
LEFT JOIN articles as a
ON t.tag_name LIKE concat('%',a.article_title,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to do this would be to have a third table that colocates the tags and the article IDs.

```
tags table
------------
tag_id  tag_name
--------------
1      travel
2      tickets
3      business
4      america

article table
-------------
article_id  article_title
---------   --------------
1           travel tips to america
2           cheap tickets for favorite destinations
3           prices for business class tickets to america

article_tags table
------------
at_id tag_id  article_id
--------------
1      1      1
2      4      1
3      2      2
4      3      2
```

This way, you can maintain a single table for all of your articles and all of your tags without having redundant rows for each tag on each article.

So, if you wanted to grab all the tags for article_id 1

```
SELECT at.id, t.tag_id, t.tag_name FROM article_tags at
INNER JOIN articles a ON (a.article_id = at.article_id)
INNER JOIN tags t ON (at.tag_id = t.tag_id)
WHERE at.article_id = 1
```

That query should output,

```
at_id    tag_id   tag_name
1        1        travel
2        4        america
```

Or, you may want to grab all the articles for a specific tag e.g "tickets"

```
SELECT a.article_name FROM article_tags at
INNER JOIN articles a ON (at.article_id = a.article_id)
INNER JOIN tags t ON (at.tag_id = t.tag_id)
WHERE t.tag_name = 'tickets'
```

That should output:

```
article_name
---------------
cheap tickets for favorite destinations
prices for business class tickets to america
```